# Как прервать завершение Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Всем привет.
Во время завершения, я в  onPause() проверяю, все ли поля были корректно заполнены.
Если нет то хотелось, что бы пользователь не смог нажать назад, пока все условия не будут соблюдены.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вам нужно переопределить метод `onBackPressed()`

К примеру:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Если поля не заполнены, то показать какое нибудь сообщение
    //иначе 
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```